# Sorting a part of Java ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

What is the **most efficient** way of sorting only a part of ArrayList? 
Say all elements from index 0 to 3 in an Arraylist which contains 10 elements.

Is there a library function available in Java?

Apart from `Collections.sort(list)` which sorts the entire List!

Writing a highly optimised custom sort function will take some work.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In Java 8+, use [`List#sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)).

```
list.subList(0,3).sort(null) ;
```

In earlier Java:

```
Collections.sort(list.subList(0,3));
```

**Note:** '3' here is excluded from sorting.

To quote the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)):

> public List subList(int fromIndex,
> int toIndex)
>
> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
> fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

Comment: this is a correct answer. Collections.sort does the sorting in place and List.subList returns a list that is backed by the original list.

Comment: There is a fencepost error in this solution, as this command will actually exclude the element in index 3.

Answer (score 6):

use the [`subList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) [inherited from `AbstractList`] method in `ArrayList`. And then use `Collections.sort()` on that sub-list. That is if *writing a highly optimised custom sort function is truly hard work*.

Comment: While "inherited from `AbstractList`" is not wrong, as such, it's mostly irrelevant. It's more important that `subList` is defined by `List`, in my opinion.

Comment: AFAIK, `List` does **NOT** define `subList`. Hence, the relevance of letting the OP know where exactly does `ArrayList` inherit that behaviour from.

Comment: @anirvan [Sure it does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-).

Comment: @TavianBarnes `List` is an interface, so what I was merely implying is that it doesn't _implement_ it, while `AbstractList` does.