# How to sort ArrayList which contains N items but to sort every 10 items

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Want to sort ArrayList which contains N number of record but my requirement is ,sorting will happen between every 10 record from the list.

Example:

I have ArrayList which contain 50 record . I want sort every 10  record from the list ,so I will get 5 sorted set.

How we can do this in Java ?

Comment: If you have made any attempt at all so far you should post the code you have written and explain what is not working.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  I can imagine a slick solution using streams, but you should show some effort first.

Comment: take 10 records -> store in a list -> sort the list -> repeat -> profit

Comment: If you have a specific question when you try this yourself, feel free to bring that question to us. This is far too broad for the scope of SO. Generally, 'giev meh teh codez' questions are not met well.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort just a sublist:

`Collections.sort(list.subList(0,10));`

Run this for every 10 elements in your list.

Got this from: [Sorting a part of Java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164902/sorting-a-part-of-java-arraylist)