# Sorting a sub-List, Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Update: I'm aware of the similarities to [Sorting a part of Java ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164902/sorting-a-part-of-java-arraylist). This question asks about the `List` interface rather than the `ArrayList` class specifically, and as such is more broad. I think it merits a separate question.

In Java, the `Arrays` class has a static method that allows you to sort a subarray within an array:

```
public static <T> void sort(
    T[] a,
    int fromIndex,
    int toIndex,
    Comparator<? super T> c)
```

I'd like to sort a `List` in a similar manner, i.e. I'd like to be able to pass in a `fromIndex` and a `toIndex` argument to `List`'s sort method. However, the [documentation for `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) indicates that its sort method only accepts a `Comparator`. Aside from converting a `List` to an `Array` and invoking the `Arrays.sort` method that accepts a range of elements, what are some good ways to sort a subsection of a `List`'s elements in Java?

Comment: @BoristheSpider you should post that as an answer. The doc for sublist supports that: "all of the algorithms in the Collections class can be applied to a subList"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164902/sorting-a-part-of-java-arraylist

Answer (score 10):

Simple - use [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

```
data.subList(start, end).sort(Comparator.naturalOrder())
```

Comment: should do this more often Boris. you're always posting answers as comments ;-).

Comment: I know, I know @Aominè - but it always seems like more effort to write an answer than just to poke someone in the right direction...

Comment: Similarly, this is how you do things like `indexOf` starting from somewhere other than the start of the list.

Comment: @AndyTurner I've always liked `List.subList(start, end).clear()` as a trick.

Comment: *Pedantic:* To match arguments of `Arrays.sort()`, it would actually be: `a.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).sort(c)`